# How to use react with asp.net MVC to create a modular site/portal

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, webpack, reactjs.net

I read all about `react`, `webpack`, `react router` and very other things
in all of their documentation and found all menus, `links` and `routes` are defined in src and compiled (bundled and minified) by `webpack` BEFORE publishing.

But I need a mechanism so:

1. Links and routes generated based on available modules and user requested (for example, a normal user *MUST NOT* see links for the manager. a solution in `react router` samples (*hiding manager links*) is so basic and not for production.
2. Do this dynamically when user requests for resource

Is there any way to do bundle or add dynamic parts (such as routing configs) to precompiled `JavaScripts` in runtime?

I'm using `asp.net` framework MVC

Comment: I upvoted you, Also, I should see your project and your implementation, but maybe my answer below helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control what level of users can see what, here is what you'll want to do:

```
if(Request.IsAuthenticated){
    if (isAdmin){
        @Html.ActionLink("Link for Managers", "Manager", "SomeFolder")
        }
        @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Somefolder2")
        @Html.ActionLink("About", "Index", "Somefolder3")
        @Html.ActionLink("Reports", "Index", "Somefolder4")

   }
```

This would allow all users see the "Home", "About", and "Reports" links, and only let admins see the "Link for Managers." This would be in your layout using razor syntax, and it's very easy to implement additional logic for user views. I hope this helps put you on the right path!

Comment: I want to render React Routes dynamically

Answer (score 0):

In fact, `react` was made for a different architecture, Backend makes `REST` APIs and `react` could be a different project and even could have `Server Side Rendering` separately. `react` call APIs for manipulating the application, So, Backend can be written in any language.

Also, I'd some experience in your situation but a little different, Unfortunately, it is not up now and I can not show my case. We make our page with `react` and bundle it by using `webpack` And finally put the `JavaScript` and `CSS` bundle file in the page.

The `Razor` `cshtml` file was a little global so the `react router` could load the page that the user wanted, but that implementation was not very good.

Some time ago I see a [`ReactJS.NET`](https://reactjs.net) website that claims a very lovely and clean integration between `react` and `asp.net`. It was so weird to me. As regards, It can help you.

Hope my answer helps you.

Comment: You mean you run webpack on server? for every request?

Comment: @HomayounBehzadian, Not at all, running `webpack` throw every request is not the proper way, we just develop and finally built bundle files by using `webpack`. then put the bundle in `cshtml` file, `react router` decides to show each page with understanding the route that the user call. I say it again. that was not the proper react app. you should read and act like [`ReactJS.NET`](https://reactjs.net/)